# How to get BroadcastReceiver messages in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, broadcastreceiver

I have here an Android device with a build in hardware barcode scanner module with a hardware scan button. I never developed an android app. but i checked the SDK of the device. The sample app uses a BroadcastReceiver to get the result of successful barcode scans.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mScanReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() { 
    ....
}
....

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(SCAN_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(mScanReceiver, filter);
}
```

Because i'm not familiar with java I don't want to develop an app to use this device. I want to use the scanner in chrome browser instead, to work with HTML5, pouchDB & javascript.

So my questions are:
Can I listen for such android Broadcasts in the chrome browser? (how?)

If this is not possible, i think about building a simple app which opens "Chrome Custom Tabs". Is it possible to pass messages from the app to its Chrome custom tabs?

Or is there another way to solve this?

Comment: "Can I listen for such android Broadcasts in the chrome browser?" -- no.

Comment: thanks for quick response. When a barcode was scanned in chrome also a keypress "F10" event will fire. Is there a way to fire an own keypress event from an android app? Or how does the scanner SDK itself produce this "F10" keypress event in chrome?

Comment: "Is there a way to fire an own keypress event from an android app?" -- not on an end user's device, except perhaps via the accessibility APIs, which require multiple levels of user permission. "Or how does the scanner SDK itself produce this "F10" keypress event in chrome?" -- my guess is that it doesn't. The hardware itself could, via USB or Bluetooth input device profiles.